# Asset pipeline won't even try to compile SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline

My setup is fairly simple default rails 3.2.1 setup. All my `.css.sass` files are in `/app/assets/stylesheets/`. I have the `sass-rails '~> 3.2.3'` gem in `:assets` group.

There's no application.css, just `main.css.sass` (used for main layout).

When i issue:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

it compiles my coffeescripts and javascripts. There are no error messages in the log. It's like it doesn't even try to compile `sass` files.

The `main.css.sass` file header looks like this:

```
//=depend_on "_globals.css.sass"
@import globals
```

The _glocals.css.sass exists in the same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

James is right and it's one of the possible solutions.

The drawback of adding all files to one manifest file is that all will be precompiled to single file - which isn't always what you want.

In my case I needed separate files (one file for each layout).

Heres how to add new manifest files:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( file1.css file2.css )
```

You don't need to have actual `file1.css`, if you have `file1.css.sass` it will be precompiled.

Comment: Thanks! This answer was pretty hard to find, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think sass needs a manifest file and by default that's application.css for a rails 3.2 app. So creating application.css and `//= require 'main'` might dove your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, but I need several stylesheets for several layouts. I solved the problem by defining new manifests to precompile, but can't answer my own question (because you have to wait 8 hours if you have less then 100 reputation or something).